# Android-sdk-osx revision 20 hello world does not build out of the box

Tags: android, macos

Running android-sdk-osx revision 20 (add-on XML Schema #5, repository XML Schema #7 (whatever that is)), I generate the default app in the recommended way and then attempt to run it in debug mode as stated here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

```
ant debug
. . .

[apkbuilder] Creating AndroidHelloWorld-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

BUILD FAILED
/Users/dsw/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:920: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/dsw/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:931: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/dsw/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:295: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: Debug Certificate expired on 3/2/10 8:46 PM
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.getDebugKey(ApkBuilder.java:283)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:390)
    at com.android.ant.ApkBuilderTask.execute(ApkBuilderTask.java:334)
. . .
```

Frankly I expect better from Google.  Anyone know how to update the Debug Certificate, of all things (really, I need a certificate to run locally?)

Answer (score 0):

Debug keys used to expire 365 days after creation. They now expire 30 years after creation. Delete the debug keystore and Eclipse will build a new one for you.

Find the location under Preferences>>Android>>Build

Comment: (1) I'm not using Eclipse; (2) What is the context for "Preferences>>Android>>Build"; there is no such path in the Android SDK manager; how do I do this just using the Android tools?

Comment: Ah, it is $HOME/.android/debug.keystore

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running Eclipse, the answer, (modified from the other answer in this thread for Eclipse by Krylez), is:

```
rm $HOME/.android/debug.keystore
```

And then build again.